# GAE: planning for exportability and relational databases

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

I'm building a web app in GAE that needs to make use of some simple relationships between the datastore entities. Additionally, I want to do what I can from the outset to make import and exportability easier, and to reduce development time to migrate the application to another platform.

I can see two possible ways of handling relationships between entities in the datastore:

- Including the key (or ID) of the related entity as a field in the entity
  OR
- Creating a unique identifier as an application-defined field of an entity to allow other entities to refer to it

The latter is less integrated with GAE, and requires some kind of mechanism to ensure the unique identifier is in fact unique (which in turn will rely on ancestor queries).

However, the latter may make data portability easier. For example, if entities are created on a local machine they can be uploaded (provided the unique identifier is unique) without problem. By contrast, relying on the GAE defined ID will not work as the ID will not be consistent from the development to the deployed environment.

There may be data exportability considerations too that mean an application-defined unique identifier is preferable.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: I think you need to just write a custom tool to export it from the GAE datastore that uses the GAE way of doing it.

Comment: Why don't you decouple the underlying entity implementation from the business logic by abstracting all low level entity access into a data access layer? In that way, when you do your migration, you would only need to change your data access layer, and the relationship design would follow the one suitable for your chosen platform instead of trying to make your current one universal across different platform paradigm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAE's datastore just doesn't export well to SQL.  There's often situations where data needs to be modeled very differently on GAE to support certain queries, ie many-to-many relationships.  Denormalizing is also the right way to support some queries on GAE's datastore.  Ancestor relationships are something that don't exist in the SQL world.

In order to import export data, you'll need to write scripts specific to your data models.

If you're planning for compatibility with SQL, use CloudSQL instead of the datastore.

In terms of moving data between dev/production, you've already identified the ways to do it.  There's no real "easy" way.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know there's not something obvious that I'm missing.